# How can I recall a numbered history command for edit?

Tags: bash, command-history

I frequently search for changes with `history | grep 'string'`

I get a list of commands in my history, along with the history line number), e.g.

```
history | grep 'git'

  755  git status
 1535  git push origin master
 1570  git merge origin/one-146
 1667  git reset --hard origin/master
```

I can now recall and execute a command in one go with `!nnn`, for example:

```
!755
git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

My question is: How can I recall a numbered history command and stay on the command line for editing and **not** execute it right away 'as is', the way that `!` does, so that I can change a couple of things before pressing the return key?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've since adopted another approach to this - using `![line-number]:p`

This prints the statement and adds it to history but doesn't actually execute it.  I then do up arrow and change it as desired.

I combine this with my `hg` alias (`alias hg='history | grep '`) to recall history commands based on some text.

Example:

```
$ hg checkout

17140   git checkout README.rdoc
17143   git checkout master
17201   git checkout README.rdoc
17204   git checkout master
17923   git checkout .bashrc
18151   git checkout v311
```

I use this in addition to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> (reverse history search) because sometimes I prefer to see an immediate list of all the possibilities for a given string rather than just the output on 1 line that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> shows.  After `hg [string]` I would then do `![line-number]search_string` as in the `hg checkout` shown above.

Answer (score 11):

If you set the `histverify` [option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-shopt), e.g.

```
shopt -s histverify
```

then all history substitutions are brought up for editing instead of being executed immediately. You would then need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice instead of once after typing `!755` to execute the command.

You can push arbitrary text onto the history list with [`history -s`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-history). Combine this with [`fc -nl`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-fc) to list a specific history entry.

```
history -s "$(fc -nl 755 755)"
```

then press <kbd>Up</kbd> to recall what is now the latest history entry.

Answer (score 6):

You can search back through the history using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. If the history entry is long use the mouse (not the keyboard, that stops the search) to copy and paste part of the command to edit back in.

As @rijsg commented, you can then use the (left and right) arrows or equivalent keys to stop the search and start editing.

Comment: Any arrow key or equivalent command (`Ctrl-a` for example) will stop the search leaving the current history entry in the command prompt, without executing it. This may or may not be enough, depending on what @Michael wants.

Answer (score 2):

If you configure your .bashrc file to use the vi editor 
at the command line it will make command line edits so much less complex.

1st, once **"set -o vi"** is enabled, you can simply hit **"<esc> k"**, 
then keep hitting **"k" to go up** the history file as it were, 
if you go past an entry, use **"j" to go down**.

NOTE:  when using vi, there are two modes:  command and edit
to enter the command mode hit the ESCAPE KEY ONCE, 
then a,A,i,I, etc. to insert.

Simple cursor pad in vi: **left=h, down=j, up=k, right=l**
http://linuxmeister.net/vi/vi-Summary.jpg

I've added all the entries needed to make this work at:
http://linuxmeister.net/Notes/bashrc-simple.html

So, based on the very helpful information above, 
I was able to use "history" and RECALL a line from "history", WITHOUT executing it.  *(THANK YOU FOR THAT POST!)*

if shopt is listed and 
histverify is "off" a ! will EXECUTE immediately,

if you've added to your .bashrc, or typed:  **shopt -s histverify**,
  then a ! allows an edit, for example:

```
history
    1  more .bashrc
    2  history
    3  shopt
    4  . ./.bashrc
    5  shopt | grep hist
    6  history
    7  alias
    8  history
    9  shopt
   10  history
```

---

--> !5

#### when I hit !5 the following command appears, but does NOT execute

### ###   if histverify is "on".

```
shopt | grep hist
cmdhist         on
histappend      on
histreedit      off
histverify      on
lithist         off
```

---

Remember that Linus and Richard created Linux and GNU tools 
to take advantage of UNIX.  The vi editor (created by Bill Joy) 
is one of the best tools to master as it is on EVERY distribution of UNIX
 and Linux.

All of the other command line editors need to be loaded and 
require additional software.  Using a GUI in Linux 
(other than Firefox, Thunderbird, and OpenOffice) 
is like towing your Diesel 4x4 with a 1968 VW Beetle... 
it'll work, but it sure doesn't make any sense.

Remember what Kernigan said about a GUI, "what you see is all you get".

Answer (score 1):

```
echo !number
```

then hit up-arrow, remove the word `echo` and edit the rest; press enter to execute.